# How to select a hover on inspector?

Tags: css, hover, scss-mixins

On my website, I want to select an element on hover and disable it.
First, I want to know how can I select this hover? Generally, how to select elements which on top of each other? If I want to select the back element.

For an instant, I want to disable black hover (not figure url) from this website

https://class.rafiee.net/
I wrote a CSS on Raw SCSS section of my moodle plugin:

```
.coursestyle2.figcaption {
display: none
}
```

But it is not working.

Update:
I found the code in page source. In fact I need to delete this part:

```
<figcaption>
                                <h3>پیکر بندی شبکه های محلی بی سیم</h3>
                                <div class="course-card">
                                <div class="coursecat">Category: <a class="" href="https://class.rafiee.net/course/index.php?categoryid=1">دانشگاه</a></div>
                                
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm coursestyle2btn">Go to course   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                <ul class="teacherscourseview"><li>Teacher: مجید رفیعی</li></ul>
                            </div>

                            </figcaption>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking here, but if u are editing the example in the provided URL and are asking how to have that black overlay be not black but transparent. It should be something like this probably.

```
.coursestyle2 figcaption {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

As to how to target the hover in the case of that example, on the element:

```
<figure class="coursestyle2">
```

Is where the hover is located on that page, and u can target it by something like this:

```
.coursestyle2:hover {
  something to do when hovering
}
```

Comment: I want to remove it entirely with its text and blue button inside.

Comment: You probably want to look for something in the code with :hover behind it and delete that part. Or if u want to be thorough, delete the html which adds the text and buttons aswell as the CSS with the :hover part as seen in the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can See on the Picture, you inspect your Element first, then click one `:hov` (2. step) then activate the `:hover` (3. Step) and then you can activate/deactivate the parameters (4. Step)

If you want to hide all the elements, you need to do this:

`.coursestyle2 figcaption{diplay:none}`

Comment: @majid: if you want to hide intire Elements with thier children, you need to add the code giving in this answer

Comment: I want to hide this section entirely:

Comment: If you want to hide the entire Section encluding all of your Courses, add this: .courses{display:none}. but whenever you add new courses, they will be hidden too. So if you want to hide specific Section like only current Courses, you need to either add a Class to this section, or target your them using pseudo-class nth-of-child